# Getting foreign keys when populating a model from a view to a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I think it's something basic yet I can't figure it out. Would appreciate some help.

Lets say we have two tables: Tv and Shows.
Shows are connected to Tv table by a TvId field.

Now in our MVC application we obviously have the models to match the two tables.
Now... I need to add a new Show !

I go to a web form, select one of the Tvs and want to add a show.

When I"m on the "New show" form that uses a Shows model.. how can I get access and pass the TvId that this show's going to be created for ?

I bound all data fields to the Show model but can't figure out how to connect a new show to its "Tv".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller, you could do something like create a new model called ShowWithTv - something like this:

```
public class ShowWithTv {
    public Show { get; set; }
    public TV { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Index(int ID) {
    var data = new ShowWithTV();
    data.Show = new Show();
    data.TV = new TV().LoadFromId(ID) // put code here to load TV from ID
    return View(data);
}
```

Then populate this with the Show details (probably blank, but might have default values), and the TV.

Then in your view change the "Inherits" at the top to be your new ShowWithTv model.

Then you will have access in the view to do this:
Model.TV.{property here}

Comment: You can put a hidden with Model.TV.ID in it, and you can output some plain text on the page somewhere that says TV: Your TV, so the user knows which TV they will be adding the show to. Does that make sense?

Comment: Sorry, not really. Can you expand or possibly you know of a place on the internet where I can read about these techniques ? I couldn't find myself unfortunately.

Comment: Here is what I'm trying and it doesn't seem to work for me... Maybe you'll be able to correct what I'm doing:

On the "Shows" form I have a hidden label "TvId" so that when the form is submitted, HOPEFULLY that field gets passed to my Controller along with the Shows class.
The hidden field value I"m trying to set with Javascript:

         (function () {
        $('#tvId').val(tvId);
    })();

But it doesn't work :(

Comment: OK I understand - try this:
$('#tvId').val(<%=Model.tvId%>);

Comment: You could also just make a hidden like this: <input type="hidden" name="TvId" value="<%=Model.TvId%>" />